# Unresolved reference - what's going on?

Tags: android, android-testing, androidx-test

I'm trying to reference an Activity in a UI test "androidTest" that is part of my main project folder, however, I keep getting the error "Unresolved reference". When I check what's happening, it looks as though my imports are trying to reference the "test" folder instead of the "main" folder...

Eg. in my src/ I have :-

/androidTest

/main

/test

It's as if /androidTest is looking for references to activities in my /test folder rather than /main folder.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: invalidate caches from android studio and  rebuild project

Comment: @sasikumar - Tried numerous times. Doesn't seem to do much.